# Microsoft Graph API Error: MailboxNotEnabledForRestAPI

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, console-application, daemon

I am creating a daemon application with c# that uses the Microsoft Graph API to send mail from specific outlook accounts in my organization.

We use client credential flows to authenticate to Azure Active Directory. The application does not need a user to log in but rather has the permissions to send mail.

My exchange environment is on-premise and our IT manager successfully ran the steps for hybrid deployment.

Below is my Code

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


private static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationConfig config = AuthenticationConfig.ReadFromJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        IConfidentialClientApplication app;

            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
                .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))
                .Build();
      
        string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{config.ApiUrl}.default" }; 

        AuthenticationResult result = null;

        try
        {
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Token acquired");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        catch (MsalServiceException ex) 
        }
        }

        if (result != null)
        {
            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(app);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            
            var message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Testing Graph",
                Importance = Importance.Normal,
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = "Body text is here."
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "jack@example.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            string emailaddress = "john@example.com";
            try
            {
                 await graphClient.Users[emailaddress].SendMail(message, SaveToSentItems: false).Request().PostAsync(); 
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
               
            }
        }
    }
```

This successfully works for a couple of runs but then stops working with the error of MailboxNotEnabledForRestAPI.
To get it to start working again I downgrade one of the nuget packages and it's able to send a few more emails. Then I upgrade the package and it works a few more times.
It doesn't seem to mind which version the packages are on, as long as I make a change to them it works for a bit.

This is an application that runs in the background and checks a specific que for any emails that need to go out. There can be hundreds of emails that need to go out with this application thru a specific employee's mailbox.

How can I get the application to continue sending all mail forever without breaking? It breaks even though I didn't make any changes to the code of the application or the settings of the exchange environment.

Comment: I would try repro the issue with MS Graph explorer or POSTMAN and see if there is an issue to isolate the issue. Before that i would check my exchange/o365 admins, if all is well, no changes been made due to that you see this issue or not.

Comment: @Dev I get the same behavior in Postman as well.

Comment: My exchange admins says there was nothing changed either

Comment: As you can repro the issue with POSTMAN it means you can isolate the issue out of your app code (if you validated in the same app flow, client credential workflow). One other thing you can do is to just make sure your hybrid deployment is inline with  recommended requirements/configuration as listed in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support) so that you can call REST without any issue for the mailbox.

Comment: The hybrid deployment is set up correctly as per your link, What else can I try?

Comment: @Dev if hybrid deployment is set up as per your link - what else can I try?

Comment: I think i provided the steps above in my last reply... try those stuff in addition to hybrid deployment as well. If nothing works and still if you face issue, consider filing Microsoft Support ticket.